# Gnome 3 Connection problem

Tags: 12.04, wireless, gnome, connection

I am new in Linux universe, I'm using the 12.04 version of the Ubuntu, and I've installed Gnome using the `apt-get`, I was getting some connections problems, I'm not sure if it was after that, but, yesterday I've used `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` and I'm receiving many messages of error. There  is a solution? What could it be?

Comment: we want to help you, but for that we need more information regarding error. Thank you.

Comment: Like I said, i've receiving many messages, from many apps this when Iam using the GNOME, now i'm using unity. Just one problem remain in this case, I can't use my printer, it just cancels the order I give to her. The errors are about Samba, Wi fi Radar, and the ubuntu itself. How can I restore my initial configurations?